# How to add pixel like activity shortcuts in launcher icon?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

Since the release of pixel series, there has been this feature to add activity shortcuts in application icon itself by long pressing the icon. I have been trying to find out a particular method by which these shortcuts can be implemented to make an app more interactive and user friendly.
[image: shortcut screen]

Comment: this option is available from Oreo version of android SDK. Check the documentation for Oreo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to add pixel like activity shortcuts in launcher icon?

**this option is available from Oreo version of android**

follow this steps to create activity shortcuts in launcher icon

> - In your app's manifest file (`AndroidManifest.xml`), find an activity whose intent filters are set to the `android.intent.action.MAIN` action and the `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` category.
> - Add a `<meta-data>` element to this activity that references the resource file where the app's shortcuts are defined:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.myapplication">
  <application ... >
     <activity
        android:name=".activity.TempActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


        <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
            android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />

    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

> - Create a new resource file: `res/xml/shortcuts.xml.`

In this new resource file, add a  root element, which contains a list of  elements. Each  element, in turn, contains information about a static shortcut, including its icon, its description labels, and the intents that it launches within the app:

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <shortcut
        android:enabled="true" // make sure shortcut is enabled true
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_check" // set icon here
        android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/collections" // message when shortcut is  disabled
        android:shortcutId="prem" // you need to give unique shortcutId
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/collections" // long lable for shortcut
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/collections">// short lable for shortcut
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="com.prem.demoapp.activity.ChatActivity"
            android:targetPackage="com.prem.demoapp" /> // you need to provide here your Activity name and target package name you application


        <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
    </shortcut>


    <shortcut
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_check"
        android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/app_name"
        android:shortcutId="compose"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/app_name"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/app_name">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="com.prem.demoapp.activity.AccountSettingActivity"
            android:targetPackage="com.prem.demoapp" />

        <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
    </shortcut>



</shortcuts>
```

output of this shortcut

[image]

for more information please read **[App Shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html#pinning)**

Comment: Good One. The code is understandable and worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use these shortcuts, if your application is targeting version 7.1+ (API level 25+).

There are three different types of these shortcuts, taken from the documentation:

> **Static shortcuts** are defined in a resource file that is packaged into an APK. Therefore, you must wait until you update your entire app
>   to change the details of these static shortcuts.
>
> **Dynamic shortcuts** are published at runtime using the ShortcutManager
>    API. During runtime, your app can publish, update, and remove its
>    dynamic shortcuts.
>
> **Pinned shortcuts** are published at runtime and also use the
>   ShortcutManager API. During runtime, your app can attempt to pin the
>   shortcut, at which time the user receives a confirmation dialog asking
>   their permission to pin the shortcut. The pinned shortcut appears in
>   supported launchers only if the user accepts the pinning request. (Only available on Android 8.0+)

These shortcuts reference at least one intent inside the app. I won't copy paste the tutorial from the documentation here, you can find everything you need to know [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html).